# how to run phantomjs on heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, phantomjs

I am trying to run phantomjs on the heroku cedar stack.

I am using a phantomjs buildpack for heroku https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.
However I followed the instructions but still cannot make it work.
When I run the command `heroku run bash` and type `phantomjs --version` it says `phantomjs: command not found`

I read things about LD_LIBRARY_PATH that needs to be set to "/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/app/vendor/phantomjs/lib", this is what i did but without success.

Is there something that i am missing ?
Where does the buildpack install the phantomjs binary exactly ? Is there a way to know the path where the binary is ?

I am using ruby 1.9.2

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: To be more precise, i want to combine ruby and phantomjs, so i am using this custom buildpack: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi, but when i push to heroku i get "Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app"

Answer (score 32):

Download the 64-bit linux binary file from phantomjs.org here http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Create a bin/ directory in your app if you do not already have one and place the binary file there.  You should then be able to test if you can run it with "heroku run 'phantomjs'" or "heroku run 'bin/phantomjs'"

Comment: Great solution, by far the easiest and quickest I've tried, AND it actually work.

Comment: Worked for me! Make sure you unpack the .bz2 file and grab the phantomjs binary if you download the compressed file primarily listed.

Comment: Great solution! Make sure you only take the "phantomjs" file inside the bin folder, not the entire downloaded folder.

Comment: Thanks! Note to other travelers: you have to do this AND add the buildpacks config described here: https://discussion.heroku.com/t/running-a-headless-browser-on-heroku/97/3

Comment: How can I download it? **Binary packages for Linux are still being prepared. Please come back again in a few days!**

Comment: You will either have to wait a few days until a Linux binary 2.0 package is prepared or try building yourself following the instruction here: http://phantomjs.org/build.html.  If you don't like either of these options you can try googling around for an old build from an unofficial source http://phantomjs.org/releases.html

Comment: This works perfectly. I didn't need the latest 2.0 so was able to apt-get install 1.9 and upload /usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs to my app's bin directory and it worked beautifully. Note: no other buildpack config was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## For phantomjs with javascript

I dont know if the previous examples are actually necessary becasue although i am working with javascript it should not be different. For me all i had to do was place the phantomjs buildpack as the first on the list of installed buildpacks on your master.

## check available buildpacks

*open terminal from the app folder and type:*

```
heroku buildpacks
```

This wll show the available buildpacks.
eg.

```
1.heroku/node.js

2.https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

As you can see the buildpack is second on this list. We need tomake it the first in the list.So, what i did was i removed the phantomjs builpack and then add it again but this time made sure its first on the list of all available buildpacks.

So, to remove a buildpack, type:

```
heroku buildpacks:remove https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

this removes the buildpack.You can check it by typing:

```
heroku buildpacks
```

Now, it should only show,

```
1.heroku/node.js
```

Great, now we add the phantomjs buildackmaking sure its first . So on terminal type:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

You can check if its first by typing:

```
heroku buildpacks
```

Now, it should be ,

```
1.https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
2.heroku/node.js
```

## Thats It!!

now, on terminal , type:

```
heroku run bash
```

once you're in bash, type

```
phantomjs --version
```

The current verion of phantomjs should be shown on the terminal.

```
2.1.1
```