# Take a screenshot using PhantomJS on Heroku + Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, phantomjs

Is it possible to use PhantomJS on a Heroku + Rails server?

Basically I want to use PHantomJS to take screenshots. The code looks really easy, but it's all in server-side JS I believe: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Any ideas how I can make use of this on my Rails project?

Comment: `Is it possible to use PhantomJS on a Heroku + Rails server?` have you tried it before?

Comment: couldn't find anything to get it started. seems to require node.js

Comment: http://bit.ly/1owwa4b :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run phantomjs on heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495463/how-to-run-phantomjs-on-heroku)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and this was the easiest solution:

> Download the 64-bit linux binary file from phantomjs.org here http://phantomjs.org/download.html
>
> Create a bin/ directory in your app if you do not already have one and place the binary file there. You should then be able to test if you can run it with "heroku run 'phantomjs'" or "heroku run 'bin/phantomjs'"

[how to run phantomjs on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495463/how-to-run-phantomjs-on-heroku)